# How to limit elasticsearch to a list of documents each identified by a unique keyword

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch document repository with ~15M documents.

Each document has an unique 11-char string field (comes from a mongo DB) that is unique to the document. This field is indexed as `keyword`.

I'm using C#.

When I run a search, I want to be able to limit the search to a set of documents that I specify (via some list of the unique field ids).

My query text uses `bool` with `must` to supply a `filter` for the unique identifiers and additional clauses to actually search the documents. See example below.

To search a large number of documents, I generate multiple query strings and run them concurrently. Each query handles up to 64K unique ids (determined by the limit on `terms`).

In this case, I have 262,144 documents to search (list comes, at run time, from a separate mongo DB query). So my code generates 4 query strings (see example below).

I run them concurrently.

Unfortunately, this search takes over 22 seconds to complete.

When I run the same search but drop the `terms` node (so it searches all the documents), a single such query completes the search in 1.8 seconds.

An incredible difference.

So my question: **Is there an efficient way to specify which documents are to be searched (when each document has a unique self-identifying keyword field)?**

I want to be able to specify up to a few 100K of such unique ids.

Here's an example of my search specifying unique document identifiers:

```
{
    "_source" : "talentId",
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 10000,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "bool" : {
                        "must" : [  {  "match_phrase" : { "freeText" : "java" } },
                                    {  "match_phrase" : { "freeText" : "unix" } },
                                    {  "match_phrase" : { "freeText" : "c#" } },
                                    {  "match_phrase" : { "freeText" : "cnn" } } ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool" : {
                        "filter" : {
                            "bool" : {
                                "should" : [
                                    {
                                        "terms" : {
                                            "talentId" : [ "goGSXMWE1Qg",  "GvTDYS6F1Qg",
                                                           "-qa_N-aC1Qg", "iu299LCC1Qg",
                                                           "0p7SpteI1Qg",  ... 4,995 more ...  ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance that rethinking this completely would be helpful? Why are you searching against a specific list of 64k IDs? Where did that list come from? Perhaps you could introduce additional attributes into your documents that match how the original search that yielded the 64k document IDs was produced (e.g. all users aged 20-40 or all drivers with Ford Mustangs or whatever is appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

@jarmod is right.

But if you don't wanna completely redo your architecture, is there some other *single* `talent`-related shared field you could query instead of thousands of `talendId`s? It could be one more simple `match_phrase` query.